# Python Tkinter Saving Point Coordinates

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Python GUI I am creating w/ Tkinter. This is my first time working w/ GUI's and Tkinter so please bear w/ me!

I am trying to save point locations/coordinates into variables. In the code I have so far, I upload a BMP image, and when I click on a certain point on the image, the point is marked. I am trying to figure out how to save the first three points' coordinates into variables in which I would use to create a best-fit ellipse that intersects all 3 of those points. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):
    # Define settings upon initialization. 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class.
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # reference to the master widget, which is the tk window
        self.master = master

        # with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet 
        exist
        self.init_window()

    # Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):
        # changing the title of our master widget
        self.master.title("GUI")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)

        # added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        # create the file object)
        analyze = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        analyze.add_command(label="Region of Interest", 
        command=self.regionOfInterest)

        # added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="Analyze", menu=analyze)
        load = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        # labels can be text or images
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def regionOfInterest(self):
        root.config(cursor="plus")
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.imgClick)


    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def imgClick(self, e):
        x = canvas.canvasx(e.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(e.y)
        pos.append((x, y))
        canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
        canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", tags="crosshair")


# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but
# you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()

# loads exact size of image
imgSize = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
tkimage =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgSize)
w, h = imgSize.size

# creates canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
canvas.create_image((w/2,h/2),image=tkimage)
canvas.pack()

# loads exact dimentsion from img size
geometry = "%dx%d" % (w,h)
root.geometry(geometry)

# creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the positions lets use a list. We can store the tuples in a class attribute.

Lets move the `imgClick` function into the class so we can take advantage of class attributes easier.

Then lets remove the `init_window` method as its redundant here.

Also lets add a counter so when we reach 3 clicks the program stops marking the map and removes the button bind.

New class attributes:

`self.pos = []`
`self.counter = 0`

Then we modify the `imgClick` method:

```
def imgClick(self, event):

    if self.counter < 3:
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        self.pos.append((x, y))
        print(self.pos)
        canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
        canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
        self.counter += 1
    else:
        canvas.unbind("<Button 1>")
        root.config(cursor="arrow")
        self.counter = 0
```

You will notice there is a print statement that will print out the saved values of `self.pos` on each click during the Analyze clicks.

Take a look at this code and let me know what you think:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.counter = 0

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        analyze = Menu(menu)

        analyze.add_command(label="Region of Interest", 
        command=self.regionOfInterest)

        menu.add_cascade(label="Analyze", menu=analyze)
        load = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def regionOfInterest(self):
        root.config(cursor="plus")
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.imgClick)


    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def imgClick(self, event):

        if self.counter < 3:
            x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            self.pos.append((x, y))
            print(self.pos)
            canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
            canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", tags="crosshair")
            self.counter += 1
        else:
            canvas.unbind("<Button 1>")
            root.config(cursor="arrow")
            self.counter = 0


root = Tk()
imgSize = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
tkimage =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgSize)
w, h = imgSize.size

canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
canvas.create_image((w/2,h/2),image=tkimage)
canvas.pack()

root.geometry("%dx%d"%(w,h))
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you provided works great! Thank you also for the step by step process and your rationale for each step, it was quite helpful

Comment: Hey! So I am trying to do 4 points instead. I tried changing it to self.counter < 4, but it still only lets me plot 3 points. Am I overlooking something?